# Directory Not Found in creating json file Unity3D

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with Unity3D. In particular, I am trying to collect data during a game session, and then save them inside a `.json` file, to be stored at a specific location. The code to store the file is the following:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class ManageJSON : MonoBehaviour
{

   private string _jsonPath; 
   private JsonObject _jsonObject;
   private string _filename = "output.json";

   void Start()
       {
           _jsonPath = Application.dataPath + "/json/";
           if (!Directory.Exists(_jsonPath))
           {
               Directory.CreateDirectory(_jsonPath);
           }
           _sessionCode = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
           _jsonPath = Path.Combine(_jsonPath, _sessionCode + "-" + _filename);
        
           WriteJsonFile();
       }
   
   public void WriteJsonFile()
       {
           string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(_jsonObject);

           using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(_jsonPath))
           {
               writer.Write(json);
           }
       }
}
```

The class `JsonObject` is the class that generates the `json` content. As an example it could be like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class JsonObject 
{
   public List<PotionData> potionData = new List<PotionData>();
}

[Serializable]
public class PotionData 
{
   public string potionName;
   public int value;
   public List<Effect> effect = new List<Effect>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Effect
{
   public string name;
   public string descr;
}
```

However, when I try to write the file, I receive this error:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\Users\username\Documents\Unity Projects\ProjectName\Assets\json\2022-05-27T10:32:13-output.json".

However, the folder is correctly created, and I cannot understand what is the problem. Can anybody help me?

I have already tried in both using `Application.persistentDataPath` instead of `Application.dataPath`, and also in not using any different location to create the file in the general project folder, but I always have the same error.

Comment: It's odd that you're getting that error specifically, but you can't use `:` in a filename on Windows.

Comment: Last time I met this problem in C# also got this same exception. Sanitizing the path when creating file helped me fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the creation of the path: in Windows paths cannot have : inside them. Correcting the creation of the session code solved this issue